# What is the current preferred method for enabling Unicode characters in mathematical formulas in LaTeX that runs on the unmodified TeX engine?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings, latex-base

I am trying to make LaTeX recognize Unicode characters in mathematical formulas.
The symbols used are already present in the original Computer Modern fonts
and are completely standard (e.g., \alpha, \Gamma, \times, \bigotimes, \biguplus),
so fonts are not an issue, the only question is how to make LaTeX recognize
the corresponding Unicode characters.

I am only interested in LaTeX that runs on the standard unmodified
TeX engine, without any extensions such as XeTeX, LuaTeX, pdfTeX, etc.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

$α⨯Γ+⨂_i A_i = ⨄_j C_j$

\end{document}
```

The intent is that the formula should expand to

```
$\alpha \times \Gamma + \bigotimes_i A_i = \biguplus_j C_j$
```

As you can see, I have tried the package `inputenc` with the `utf8` option,
as well as the `utf8x` option, and also the package `ucs` with the `mathletters` option.

The latter at least appears to support α and Γ, but some sources claim that `ucs` and `utf8x` are obsolete.
None of these packages seem to support \times, \bigotimes, or \biguplus.
All of this is quite confusing, since the suggested nonobsolete `utf8` option appears to support none of the above symbols.

I am using plain TeX for myself,
where it is trivial to define macros for all UTF-8 characters corresponding to the mathematical symbols provided by plain TeX,
which is exactly what I did in my own [macro package](https://dmitripavlov.org/tex/dpmac.tex) for plain TeX.
However, for my collaborators the usage of LaTeX is often necessary,
so I am also looking for a proper LaTeX solution.

**What is the current preferred method for enabling Unicode characters in mathematical formulas in LaTeX that runs on the unmodified TeX engine?**

I am only interested in the most standard subset of mathematical symbols that are already present in plain TeX.
Presumably, at least these standard symbols are supported by LaTeX,
which would result in a solution that is more efficient than
defining every single Unicode character used in the document via
the commands `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` or `\newunicodechar`.

I emphatically repeat that I am only looking for solutions that use the standard unmodified TeX engine,
which is dictated by the intended application (submission of articles to mathematics journals).
Please do not suggest or mention solutions that need XeTeX, LuaTeX, pdfTeX, etc., these are completely useless.
Packages like `unicode-math` or `fontspec` do not run on the unmodified TeX engine, please do not suggest them.

Comment: You will have to declare the set with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter, I don't think that there is some package which has done this already. Btw; latex requires the  etex extensions these days, so doesn't work on an unmodified tex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Plenty of journals still use TeX Live 2016 or earlier, whose version of LaTeX does not require e-TeX.  But e-TeX is not a concern for me, other extensions that are not supported by many journals are.

Comment: well `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` should work in older latex too. I wouldn't use ucs. While it has more characters predeclared it is not really compatible. It is better to invest the time to setup the set for utf8+ inputenc

Comment: Late to the party, but here's my two cent: one of the many advantages of TeX over word processors is that it *really* processes its input. So you don't need a big keyboard with thousands of characters to input math formulas. For instance, Unicode dictates that a text alpha is *not* the same as a math alpha and using α (U+3B1) is not the same as using  (U+1D6FC).

Comment: @egreg: I am not trying to map command sequence (like \alpha) to Unicode characters like U+03B1 or U+1D6FC.  I want to map Unicode characters to command sequences.  Your comment is equally applicable to the ASCII "a" (U+0061) and Unicode's mathematical "" (U+1D44E), which, supposedly, should be used outside respectively inside formulas.  Yet somehow TeX uses the ASCII "a" for both, and this does not create any problems or ambiguities.  I am asking for the same functionality for symbols like "α" and "⊗".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am only interested in the most standard subset of mathematical symbols that are already present in plain TeX. Presumably, at least these standard symbols are supported by LaTeX, which would result in a solution that is more efficient than defining every single Unicode character used in the document via the commands `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`

LaTeX supports UTF-8 decoding by default (or in old releases you can use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to enable it, but the individual characters are not set up for math so you need to define them with for example

```
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\alpha}
```

so

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\alpha}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2A2F}{\times}% not the standard mapping
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0393}{\Gamma}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2A02}{\bigotimes}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2A04}{\biguplus}

\begin{document}

$α⨯Γ+⨂_i A_i = ⨄_j C_j$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason why the LaTeX team decided not provide a package that would do this for all the standard math symbols (e.g., those present in plain TeX), or is it just an inadvertent omission that may be rectified in future releases?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov there is almost no pressure to do this (most people prefer to use the command forms) and it is hard to get default mappings that please everyone eg `\times` would certainly be  U+00D7 not the U+2A2F that you used. Many people already have U+03B1  mapped to alpha for use in text and `\alpha` is a math command..  better to let people define the ones they need.

Comment: Mapping U+2A2F to \ifmmode\times\else\texttimes\fi would fit the needs of the overwhelming majority of users, since it works both inside and outside of formulas.  (And, of course, one can still redefine a particular character, if desired.)  In any case, thanks a lot for the authoritative answer.

Comment: The above works fine for me but it doesn't work for chess symbols, e.g. $♘$. The error message says I can fix it with \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
but \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2658}{\wknight} results in the error message: Undefined control sequence. I'm using the latest version of TexShop. Can anyone explain how to get this to work?

Comment: @GeorgeColpitts TexShop is not involved, that's just the editor you used to write the file.  `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2658}{\wknight}` defines `♘` to be the non standard command `\wknight` so naturally that gives an undefined command error unless you define it. One of the chess / skak pakages perhaps?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx David. You essentially answered my question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679501/xelatex-does-not-show-unicode-symbol/

Comment: @GeorgeColpitts this question is phrased only applying to 8 bit latex or pdflatex, with 8 bit fonts, the other question (or at least its answer) does not apply to (pdf)latex, it is for using OpenType fonts with lualatex or xelatex unicode tex systems.